# How to allow search engines to search through PDF file attached to my Joomla! article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, search

On my Joomla 3 website, there are articles which contains `PDF` files. My website is already listed to search engine (e.g Google) but my attached `PDF` files seems not listed yet. When I type small parts of the text from randomly chosen `PDF` in the search engine, it says no result is found.

In my former HTML website, this used to work: my former website appeared in the search results. The website has been online for about two months now.

Any idea, how to make search engine look into the mentioned/attached `PDF` files?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is more likely, SEO related question. Joomla has nothing to do with that. But still I can guide you to a nice explanation.

https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/make-your-pdfs-work-well-google-and-other-search-engines

Hope this will help.

Comment: Your PDF files should be text files & not scaned copies. Google and any other search engines does not search text from scan copies.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension for this. You can look it up at the JED, here:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/search-a-indexing/site-search/os-pdf-indexer

It works only when you have pdf-files that are directly 'printed' from a text-file, not for pdf's that are only an image of a text.

When the pdf-files are public over time Google searchbots will find them and index them.

Comment: Unfortunately the extension is not free, but thank you for the link.